# How to find a broker / market where to buy a certain stock?

Tags: stock-exchanges, european-union, europe

I know a certain stock can have a different *ticker* based on the market where it's traded (Wall Street, Frankfurt, Milan,...).

What I don't know is : how do I identify the market (and possibly the broker which allows me to buy that specific stock) for a specific stock?

To bring a concrete example : a market (and / or broker) in Europe (so I guess German stock market , or perhaps Milan in Italy) to buy this stock

https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/forecasts?s=ABCN:CVE

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as typing the company name into the https://markets.ft.com/data/equities search bar.  In your case, for "ABcann Global Corp":

https://markets.ft.com/data/search?query=ABcann+Global+Corp

[image]